# Can I "alias" or deduplicate connection managers in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I've made multiple SSIS packages and integrated them into a single package by copy-pasting the sequence containers into a single `dtsx` file

As a result I now have multiple connection managers all pointing to the same 2 places (since they got copied over with each sequence container and renamed themselves)

Is there a way to consolidate them together so that I can change the connection string in only one of the duplicates to reflect the change throughout the package?

(I know that I can manually change all the tasks to use the same connection string, but want to avoid that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `ConnectionString` property of more than one ConnectionManager to the same **variable**. That will allow you to change the value once and have it applied to all the connections.

However, you'll still have to go through all the ConnectionManagers and set their `ConnectionString` property to the variable manually. (Unless, of course, you want to get fancy with either editing the .dtsx file manually, or writing a .NET application to programmatically update the package.) It might well be easier to delete all the extra ConnectionManagers and update the tasks and components manually.

Comment: I am upvoting this because I really think the easiest way to deduplicate is to manually edit the .dtsx file. Some simple find/replace on the connectionManagerID=<GUID> will quickly point your data flow objects to point at the correct connection objects.

Answer (score 1):

Each of those connection managers is going to get a new `ID` property when you paste them in. When they are used in things like `Execute SQL Tasks` they display the friendly name of the connection manager but under the sheets, that GUID is stored. This is why you can rename Connection Manager A to Connection Manager B and vice versa and Tasks will still use the "right" CM.

An approach that would allow you to continue having the existing connection managers but only have 2 things to configure would be to create 2 variables, `User::ConnectionManagerAConnectionString` and `User::ConnectionManagerBConnectionString` Assign the value of those variables to be the actual connection string from the package, so something like `Data Source=localhost\DEV2012;Initial Catalog=FOO;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;`

Armed with those two variables, then on each of your Connection Managers, right click on them and in the Properties window, find Expressions and click the ellipses. Select the `ConnectionString` property and in the Expression, assign your variable.

[image]

Now when your package runs, all of those Connection Managers are configured from those expressions. If you need to change those values, you can either edit the package or apply a run-time configuration through dtexec or use the Configurations option of SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, you are going to have to do this manually I am afraid. Besides, you don't want 5 connection managers in your job that all connect to the same DB.